# adding multiple columns to a dataframe using df.apply and a lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I am trying to add multiple columns to an existing dataframe with df.apply and a lambda function. I am able to add columns one by one but not able to do it for all the columns together. 
My code

```
def get_player_stats(player_name):
    print(player_name)
    resp = requests.get(player_id_api + player_name)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        # This means something went wrong.
        print('Error {}'.format(resp.status_code))

    result = resp.json()
    player_id = result['data'][0]['pid']

    resp_data = requests.get(player_data_api + str(player_id))
    if resp_data.status_code != 200:
        # This means something went wrong.
        print('Error {}'.format(resp_data.status_code))

    result_data = resp_data.json()

    check1 = len(result_data.get('data',None).get('batting',None))
#    print(check1)
    check2 = len(result_data.get('data',{}).get('batting',{}).get('ODIs',{}))
#    check2 = result_data.get(['data']['batting']['ODIs'],None)
#    print(check2)
    if check1 > 0 and check2 > 0:
        total_6s = result_data['data']['batting']['ODIs']['6s']
        total_4s = result_data['data']['batting']['ODIs']['4s']
        average = result_data['data']['batting']['ODIs']['Ave']
        total_innings = result_data['data']['batting']['ODIs']['Inns']
        total_catches = result_data['data']['batting']['ODIs']['Ct']
        total_stumps = result_data['data']['batting']['ODIs']['St']
        total_wickets = result_data['data']['bowling']['ODIs']['Wkts']
        print(average,total_innings,total_4s,total_6s,total_catches,total_stumps,total_wickets)    
        return np.array([average,total_innings,total_4s,total_6s,total_catches,total_stumps,total_wickets])
    else:
        print('No data for player')
        return '','','','','','',''
```

```
cols = ['Avg','tot_inns','tot_4s','tot_6s','tot_cts','tot_sts','tot_wkts']
for col in cols:
    players_available[col] = ''

players_available[cols] = players_available.apply(lambda x: get_player_stats(x['playerName']) , axis =1)
```

I have tried adding columns explicitly to the dataframe but still i am getting an error

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky, since in pandas the apply method evolve through versions.

In my version (0.25.3) and also the other recent versions, if the function returns `pd.Series` object then it works.

In your code, you could try to change the return value in the function:

```
return pd.Series([average,total_innings,total_4s,total_6s,
                  total_catches,total_stumps,total_wickets])

return pd.Series(['','','','','','',''])
```

Comment: @cvg should work, could you give it a try and let me know if the problem stays?